# How do I force Photos on Mac to upload photos to iCloud Photo Library when syncing stalls out?

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

Is there any way to force Photos to upload/sync photos?

I often get into a state where Photos is just sitting on a sync and showing, for example, showing "Syncing 140 photos to iCloud" but literally doing nothing - Activity Monitor shows zero network traffic. The photos UI shows so little useful information about the syncing state and it is frustrating.

iCloud Photos is turned on. This happens both when the machine is plugged in and not, and over both wifi and ethernet. It's almost as if some throttling mechanism is happening, but I literally have nothing else going on on my system.

Is there a terminal command to either force the upload or at least see why things are stalled?

Happening (at the moment) on Ventura 13.2. (And have of course restarted the app, the machine, even the internet once on a whim.)

Comment: Restart the computer. If that doesn't fix it, you just have to wait.

Comment: It happens to me and it's so frustrating. Apple doesn't let us control the sync